# How can I print the elements of a vector as a ordered list using a range-based loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector, range, c++14

Ex:

```
vector<string> myVec = {apple, banana, grape}
```

How can I print these elements as an ordered list using a range-based loop

Output:

```
1 apple 
2 banana
3 grape
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you mind showing us some code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access index in range-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397532/access-index-in-range-for-loop)

Comment: when you say ordered list, do you mean to sort it, or keep the order?

Comment: Duplicate is correct in the general sense, but there are work-arounds for the case of `vector` and `array`. Te answers below won't work for any other containers due to lack of contiguous storage.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of Jeffrey's answer, but without additional variable:

```
for (const auto& s : myVec)
{
  std::cout << &s - &myVec[0] << " " << s << "\n";
}
```

This, of course, prints a "correct" 0-based index. Feel free to add `1` to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using boost ranges really simplifies things [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b9BmWTONnqnYCya9)

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;

std::vector<std::string> myVec = {"apple", "banana", "grape"};

for (const auto& element : myVec | indexed(1))
{
    std::cout << element.index() << " " << element.value() << "\n";
}
```

Produces

```
1 apple
2 banana
3 grape
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
    size_t position = 1;
    for(const auto& s: myVec)
    {
        std::cout << position << " " << s << "\n";
        position++;
    }
```

as in

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

vector<string> myVec = {"apple", "banana", "grape"};

int main()
{
    size_t position = 1;
    for(const auto& s: myVec)
    {
        std::cout << position << " " << s << "\n";
        position++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I assumed OP was asking about, well, the range-based part as stated. It would be trivial to add the position.

Answer (score 0):

With range-v3, you could write:

```
for (auto [i, val] : myVec | ranges::views::enumerate) 
{
  std::cout << i << ' ' << val << "\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3j1zo1).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good issue for the original `for` loop:

```
const size_t quantity = myVec.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  cout << (i + 1) << "    " << myVec[i] << "\n";
}
```

Simple, effective.  Don't knock the old stuff. :-)