# Skip nth element of the range with views

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I need to skip only **one** nth element from the range.

The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/79MfY9x8f) below does this, but I guess this could be written shorted with ranges/views without having this intermediate `src`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    const int skip_pos = 5;

    auto range = std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end());

    auto start = range | std::views::take(skip_pos);
    auto end = range | std::views::drop(skip_pos + 1);
    auto src = {start, end};
    auto seq = src | std::views::join;

    for (auto& v : seq) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest the shorter form for this?

Comment: I think this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209974/11027401

Comment: @sav, thank you for the link, but I am not sure it leads to shorter code. I am mostly looking for native ranges/views solution for this and I guess it should exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the [enumerate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) will be the shortest way to do this, there is also a [concat](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2542r0.html), but it is not yet in the standard.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> values = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    // concat is only in range-v3 library
    const auto f = values | std::views::take(5);
    const auto s = values | std::views::drop(6);
    for (auto v : ranges::views::concat(f, s)) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }

    // that is supported on C++23
    for (auto [idx, v] : values | std::views::enumerate) {
        if ( idx != 5 )
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }

    // one more example on enumerate with filter
    const auto func = [](auto &&pair){ return std::get<0>(pair) != 5; };
    auto view = values | std::views::enumerate | std::views::filter(func) | std::views::values;
    for (auto v : view) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M7vhe93v4

Comment: Thank you. My idea is to use the view further; the print was for debug/demo purposes only. I my case I need to pass it to `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare`. Is there a way to get range/view from it for further work?

Comment: @Damir Tenishev, I've updated the example for enumerate with the filter view, the `view` variable can be used in `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare`

Comment: Thank you again. From the perspective of lazy evaluations, performance and intermediate objects in memory, would this code be more efficient than mine or they have the same outcome?

Comment: View is created for a constant time, so the actual work is performed, when you iterate through the view. For this case maybe your solution will be a bit faster, because in enumerate we are checking the position by additional if. In your solution, the ranges will be already divided. You can try to measure it in compiler explorer. The ideal solution is to use concat, but unfortunately it is not in the standard.